# Save/Get ObservableCollection to/from Roaming

Tags: c#, json, windows-store-apps, observablecollection, win-universal-app

I'm making a Universal windows store app and I have an ObservableCollection.

What I want is to `save` the data from the ObservableCollection somewhere so that the data can sync between desktop and phone that have the same universal app, and then I need to be able to `get` this data so that I can update the ObservableCollection.

I haven't done anything like this before, so I'm not sure how to proceed... Do I need to save this to an XML file, and if so, how will I sync it between the different devices. The only storage methods I know how to use are:

```
     ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["key"] = "something"; 
     //Which stores "something" in local storage with key "key".

     ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["key"] = "something";
     //Which stores "something" in user's  Microsoft account storage with key "key".
```

Last one I think looks like to what I actually want, but it wouldn't be practical to save all my ObservableCollection items and properties like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to write it in a file in the app data roaming folder; app settings aren't very convenient to store collections. You can use XML, JSON or anything else. These days the trend is to use JSON, so here's an example.

Serialization:

```
var folder = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("collection.json", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collection);
    await writer.WriteAsync(json);
}
```

Deserialization:

```
var folder = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("collection.json");
using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    string json = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    var collection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<YourClass>>(json);
}
```

(using [JSON.NET](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/))

Comment: Thank you very much!!! :D Works like a charm ;)
Do you also know if this data will be erased if I released an Update of the app?

Comment: @user2975038, I don't think to, but I don't have much experience building Windows Store apps...

Comment: Updates in the Store will not wipe the data. Sometimes it can get wiped during development with Visual Studio, but your customers won't see this.